# Eliminar parámetros de un objeto almacenado en una BBDD db4o con Java

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, class, db4o

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para clase. En él, tengo que crear una pequeña y sencilla base de datos con db4o, con cuatro escuderías. la escudería va en una clase llamada Escuderia y tiene los parámetros: String nombreCoche, String paisCoche, Piloto pilotoUno, Piloto pilotoDos.
Piloto es también una clase con los parámetros: String nombre, int edad, String pais.
En un método tengo que buscar la o las escuderías que sean del país Austria y eliminar sus dos pilotos. Entonces he hecho este código:

```
/**
 * Borrar los pilotos de la escudería de Austria.
 * 
 * @param dataBase 
 */
public void opcionCinco(ObjectContainer dataBase){
    Query query = dataBase.query();
    query.constrain(Escuderia.class);
    Constraint constra4 = query.descend("paisCoche").constrain("Austria").equal();
    ObjectSet res = query.execute();
    mostrarBBDD(res);
}
```

Este método me da el resultado que quiero. Me muestra el siguiente resultado:

> Escuderia{nombreCoche=Red Bull Racing, paisCoche=Austria, pilotoUno=Piloto{nombre=Max Verstappen, edad=24, pais=Pa�ses Bajos}, pilotoDos=Piloto{nombre=Sergio P�rez, edad=31, pais=M�xico}}

Lo que quiero es en ese mismo método que he creado que de ese resultado me borre esos dos pilotos.

Gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Borrar los pilotos de la escudería de Austria.
 *
 * @param dataBase
 */
public void opcionCinco(ObjectContainer dataBase) {
    ObjectSet<Escuderia> escuderias = dataBase.query(Escuderia.class);
    while (escuderias.hasNext()) {
        Escuderia escuderia = escuderias.next();
        if (escuderia.getPaisCoche().equals("Austria")) {
            // Establecer los pilotos de la escudería en null o crear un nuevo array vacío
            escuderia.setPilotoUno(null);
            escuderia.setPilotoDos(null);

            // Guardar los cambios en la base de datos
            dataBase.store(escuderia);
        }
    }
}
```

Por si a alguien le puede ayudar.